# fatal: pathspec 'composer.lock' did not match any files

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, heroku, composer-php

When I use the command:

```
git add composer.lock
```

inside the folder of my project I get the message:

> fatal: pathspec 'composer.lock' did not match any files

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does the file exist? That's the error I'd expect Git to return if there wasn't a file with that name in the directory.

Comment: Hi @iainn! No, the file does not exist. Sorry for my ignorance, but does the "git add composer.lock" command not add "composer.lock" to the project folder? Is it necessary to have "composer.lock" in the project folder to run the "git add composer.lock" command?

Comment: `git add` adds an existing file to version control, but Git can't create any files itself - it doesn't know anything about how your project works. If you don't have a `composer.lock` file, it probably means you need to run `composer install`.

Comment: ooh ok, I get it! thanks for your explanation, it was excellent! I do not think I run the `composer install` command, I'll run the command as soon as I get home. Is it correct to run the `composer install` in the project folder?

Comment: @HenriqueTavares, probably, but we don't know anything about your project. Please remember that we only have the information you give us. It might be a good idea to read [Composer's getting started guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was install the xml from my php version. 
In my case, my version is 7.1, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

So I used the commands:

```
composer install

composer update
```

And finally I was able to add the composer.lock command:

```
git add composer.lock
```